# AWS CloudFomation: fail to create RDS resource alongside with ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am deploying my Laravel application to the AWS using CloudFormation. I am creating a ElasticBeanstalk resource and a RDS database resource. But my template is failing to create the RDS database resource when I tried to deploy it.

This is my template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "Pathein Directory web application deployment template."
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Default: 'PatheinDirectory'
    Type: String
  InstanceType:
    Default: 't2.micro'
    Type: String
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
  DBInstanceIdentifier:
    Type: String
  DBName:
    Type: String
  DBUsername:
    Type: String
  DBClass:
    Type: String
    Default: 'db.t2.micro'
  DBAllocatedStorage:
    Type: String
    Default: '5'
  DBPassword:
    Type: String

Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com

Resources:
  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2 instances
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp:
            Ref: SSHLocation

  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3306'
          ToPort: '3306'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref WebServerSecurityGroup

  WebDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstanceIdentifier
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref DBSecurityGroup
```

This is the error I got in the log.

```
 {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/566c9fa0-e55d-11ea-a9aa-06d4f42323aa",
            "EventId": "630d0ba0-e55d-11ea-ad8b-06dbc2ac1616",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "patheindirectory",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/566c9fa0-e55d-11ea-a9aa-06d4f42323aa",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-23T16:26:24.461000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to create: [DBSecurityGroup]. . Rollback requested by user."
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/566c9fa0-e55d-11ea-a9aa-06d4f42323aa",
            "EventId": "DBSecurityGroup-CREATE_FAILED-2020-08-23T16:26:23.732Z",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "DBSecurityGroup",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "patheindirectory-DBSecurityGroup-1CEIY8676LHK2",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-23T16:26:23.732000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_FAILED",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Invalid id: \"patheindirectory-WebServerSecurityGroup-188BHLOGKHGJ\" (expecting \"sg-...\") (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGroupId.Malformed; Request ID: c2bd97d8-b31b-
4024-8bc2-6eb34cdf873e)",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"GroupDescription\":\"Database security group\",\"SecurityGroupIngress\":[{\"FromPort\":\"3306\",\"ToPort\":\"3306\",\"IpProtocol\":\"tcp\",\"SourceSecurityGroupId\":\"patheindirectory-WebServerS
ecurityGroup-188BHLOGKHGJ\"}]}"
        },
```

How can I fix it?

I also tried changing to !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId for VPCSecurityGroups of WebDatabase. I got the following error this time.

```
{
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/6c67eb50-e5e6-11ea-add8-0236eb75a142",
            "EventId": "79c7afb0-e5e6-11ea-af24-06a6741d3858",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "patheindirectory",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/6c67eb50-e5e6-11ea-add8-0236eb75a142",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-24T08:47:43.645000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to create: [DBSecurityGroup]. . Rollback requested by user."
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/6c67eb50-e5e6-11ea-add8-0236eb75a142",
            "EventId": "DBSecurityGroup-CREATE_FAILED-2020-08-24T08:47:42.895Z",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "DBSecurityGroup",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "patheindirectory-DBSecurityGroup-182TKIWG65TDC",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-24T08:47:42.895000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_FAILED",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Invalid id: \"patheindirectory-WebServerSecurityGroup-JHXG6FOXICS3\" (expecting \"sg-...\") (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code:
400; Error Code: InvalidGroupId.Malformed; Request ID: 1384f7a7-ee62-4b93-a291-28a460e9d1da)",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"GroupDescription\":\"Database security group\",\"SecurityGroupIngress\":[{\"FromPort\":\"3306\",\"ToPort\":\"3306\",\"IpProto
col\":\"tcp\",\"SourceSecurityGroupId\":\"patheindirectory-WebServerSecurityGroup-JHXG6FOXICS3\"}]}"
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the logical id of the security groups (which is its name).

The parameters for both `SourceSecurityGroupId` and `VPCSecurityGroups` are expecting security group IDs instead.

To do this you would need to use the `GroupId` attribute of the security groups instead as shown in the below updated template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "Pathein Directory web application deployment template."
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Default: 'PatheinDirectory'
    Type: String
  InstanceType:
    Default: 't2.micro'
    Type: String
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
  DBInstanceIdentifier:
    Type: String
  DBName:
    Type: String
  DBUsername:
    Type: String
  DBClass:
    Type: String
    Default: 'db.t2.micro'
  DBAllocatedStorage:
    Type: String
    Default: '5'
  DBPassword:
    Type: String

Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com

Resources:
  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2 instances
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp:
            Ref: SSHLocation

  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3306'
          ToPort: '3306'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt WebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId

  WebDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstanceIdentifier
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

Also as a suggestion for your templates, for certain parameters (such as the key name) you can use [AWS Specific Parameter Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types). Additionally for secure information such as passwords use the `NoEcho` attribute in the parameter.

Comment: Hi, I used this and it is still failing.

Comment: It worked for me, could you please share the error message you're now receiving?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question. Please, have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Did you use the exact template I included in my answer? :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)